# How to fake database operations in Unit test?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, moq, mstest

I am writing the unit tests for my class library, There is a method for which I am trying to write tests. this method makes some database calls to get data from the database and inserts data into some tables. I want this to be fake. So it should like it is doing on actual database tables but actually it should not affect the original database.

I have not done this before, But I have tried the below way.

```
private Mock<DBService> _dBService;
MyDLL _myDll;
public UnitTest1()
{
    _dBService = new Mock<DBService>();
    _myDll= new MyDLL (_dBService.Object);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var response = _myDll.TestMethod(data);
    ...
}

public string TestMethod(List<long> data)
{
    var temp = _dbService.GetDataFromDB(data);
    ...
    ...
    _dbService.InsertIntoTable(someData);
}
```

I have used [MOQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) to fake the `DBService`, because all the database-related methods are implemented in the `DBService` class.

Also, If I try to get data from the database by directly using the `_dbService` in the test, it returns `null`. but it works as expected when it is called inside the `TestMethod`.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var response = _dbService.GetDataFromDB(data); //returns null ?? why?
    ...
}
```

**Update**: Adding definition of GetDataFromDB

```
public List<Transaction> GetDataFromDB(List<long> ids)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(ids.GetType());
    using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, ids);
        string xmlId = textWriter.ToString();

        var parameters = new[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("@xml", DbType.String) { Value = xmlId }
        };

        return _dataAccess
            .CallProcedure<Transaction>("GetTransactionDetails", parameters).ToList();
    }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public double? Amount { get; set; }

    public long? CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So, you all done right. What is problem?

Comment: @TemaTre it’s is inserting data into the original database table and when calling the dbService method directly in tha test, it is returning null instead of data

Comment: You need to tell the mock what to return when that method is called: `_dbService.Setup(x => x.GetDataFromDB(It.Is.Any<List<long>>)).Returns(whateverYouWant);`

Comment: @sellotape But I want the data`whatever`  to be returned from the database

Comment: Then you’re no longer "unit testing". The point of a mock is to _not_ do the real thing. If you want a hybrid that reads from the database but doesn’t write, then change `whateverYouWant` above to call the real service and return what it returns (you can access the passed parameters in `.Returns()` - check the Moq docs). That’s unlikely to run on a build server with limited credentials and network access, though, and will be (relatively) very slow.

Comment: @sellotape my intention is to test the method as it is running on real data, but its fake

Comment: @sellotape what about my first question?

Comment: It’s not clear what your first question is; please clarify.

Comment: @sellotape TestMethod makes some database calls to get data from the database and inserts data into some tables. I want this to be fake. So it should like it is doing on actual database tables but actually it should not affect the original database.see the definition of `TestMethod`

Comment: What is `_dataAccess`?

Comment: _dataAccess is of type interface, which is coming from a dll which is used for database operations @PeterCsala

Comment: I got it, but which framework are you using? Entity Framework, NHibernate, Dapper or something else?

Comment: @PeterCsala Dapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm didn't understand what you want to test with your code, but to solve your problem you need to do this:

First you need to implement an interface in your DBService:

`class DBService : IDBService`

Of course you need to declare the public methods of DBService in this interface.

Then you mock the interface instead concrete class:

```
  _dbService = Mock<IDBService>();
```

Now you can setup your methods.

To solve the first problem (inserting in real database) you setup your method and then call it's mock:

```
  _dbService.Setup(x =>  ​x.InsertIntoTable(it...));
  _dbService.Object.InsertTable(...);
```

To solve the second problem, you should use `.Returns()` method passing your Mock result

```
  _dbService.Setup(x =>  ​x.GetDataFromDB(It.IsAny<List<long>>)).Returns(YourMockedResult);
  
  _dbService.Object.GetDataFromDB(...);
```

If you're any doubt about the implementation, here in docs have a lot of examples:

https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

**Update**

I tryied to simulate your scenario and this code works fine (using .net test framework):

```
//Create an interface for your DBService
public interface IDBService
{
    List<Transaction> GetDataFromDB(List<long> ids);

    void InsertIntoTable(List<long> data);
}

//DLL class now receive a interface by dependency injection instead a concrete class
public class MyDLL
{
    private readonly IDBService _dbService;
    public MyDLL(IDBService dbService)
    {
        _dbService = dbService;
    }

    public string TestMethod(List<long> data)
    {
        var temp = _dbService.GetDataFromDB(data);//will be returned yourMockedData and assigned to temp

        _dbService.InsertIntoTable(data);

        //... rest of method implementation...

        return string.Empty; //i've returned a empty string because i don't know your whole method implementation
    }
}

//Whole method class implementation using .net test frameork
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private Mock<IDBService> _dbService;
    MyDLL _myDll;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _dbService = new Mock<IDBService>();
        
        //setup your dbService
        _dbService.Setup(x => x.InsertIntoTable(new List<long>()));

        //data that will be returned when GetDataFromDB get called
        var yourMockedData = new List<Transaction>
        {
            {
                new Transaction{ Amount = 1, CompanyId = 123, ID = 123}
            },
            {
                new Transaction{ Amount = 2, CompanyId = 321, ID = 124}
            }
        };

        _dbService.Setup(x => x.GetDataFromDB(new List<long>())).Returns(yourMockedData);

        //instantiate MyDll with mocked dbService
        _myDll = new MyDLL(_dbService.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        //Testing MyDll.TestMethod()
        var response = _myDll.TestMethod(new List<long>());
        //Assert...Whatever do you want to test
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        //Testing dbService deirectly
        var response = _dbService.Object.GetDataFromDB(new List<long>());
        //Assert...Whatever do you want to test
    }
}
```

Comment: what about my first question?

Comment: You should use something like: Returns( (List<long> x) => YourMockResult). It'll override your real method behavior. I've updated my answer with that.

Comment: what about data insertion?

Comment: Do the same in your insert method: _dbService.Setup(x =>  ​x.InsertIntoTable(it...))...

Comment: I have updated my answer with detailed info about both error you have

Comment: again you are not getting my point, how will I get value of `YourMockResult`?

Comment: What is the signature of GetDataFromDB? I'll try to make an complete example.

Comment: please check update section in th question

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and efforts. I  tried as you described in your answer, but it is still inserting the records into the actual database.

Comment: Man, please review your code because when you do this: "_dbService.Setup (x => x.InsertIntoTable (new List <long> ()))" the real method is not even called

Comment: I have checked many times, its the same code as you have

Comment: Can you share your whole code in a git repository? So I can debug

Comment: I have uploaded it on google drive, please let me know your email id, I will share the link with you

Comment: Sorry, for security reasons i don't download files. Maybe you can create an github repository

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to upload the project on github

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use an in-memory data context where schema for your real database is replicated in-memory of your unit test with an
ORM like Entity Framework (which is part of the .NET Framework libraries) to abstract your queries and stored procedures into testable classes. This would clean up your data access C# code and make it more testable.

To use your test data context with Entity Framework, try a tool such as Entity Framework Effort (https://entityframework-effort.net/) or if you are using .NET Core, the built-in in-memory provider using EF Core. I have an example in my site where I use in-memory providers in .NET Core (http://andrewhalil.com/2020/02/21/using-in-memory-data-providers-to-unit-test-net-core-applications/).

Directly testing backend SQL objects (from test databases) like stored procedures or large datasets is the same as integration testing, which is different from what you are aiming to achieve here. In this case use mocking for your unit tests and integration testing to test the actual backend stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put my 2 cents in here.

From my experience, attemtps to mock/replace a data storage for tests is usually not a good idea, due to the limitations and behavior differences of the mocks/in-memory databases in comparison to the real database.

Moreover mocks usually lead to fragile tests due to the way assertions are made, as you basically depend on the implementation details of the system under tests instead of examining just its public surface. By asserting things like "this service called another service 2 times after this method is executed" you are making your tests aware of logic, which they shouldn't be aware of. It's an internal detail, which is possibly a subject of frequent changes, so any application update will lead to test failures, while the logic is still correct. And high amount of tests false positives isn't surely good.

I'd rather recommend that you use a real database for tests, which need access to data storage, while trying to keep a quantity of such tests minimal. Most of the logic should be covered by unit tests instead. It might require some application design changes, but those are usually for good.

And there are different tricks then to achieve the best performance of tests, which are using a real database:

- Separate tests, which mutate data, from the read-only ones and start the latter in parallel without any data cleanup;
- Use the only optimized script to insert/delete test data. You might find [Reseed](https://github.com/v-zubritsky/Reseed) library I'm developing currently helpful for that aim. It's able to generate both insert and delete scripts for you and execute those fast. Or check out [Respawn](https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn) which could be used for database cleanup;
- Use database snapshots for the restore, which might be faster than full insert/delete cycle;
- Wrap each test in transaction and revert it afterwards;
- Parallelize your tests by using a pool of databases instead of the only. Docker and [TestContainers](https://github.com/HofmeisterAn/dotnet-testcontainers) could be suitable here;